# IPython notebook doesn't open.

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-webbrowser

I'm using Anaconda version 2.2.0 and I'm trying to launch Ipython Notebbok on Windows. 
But instead launch the borwser, a Microsoft Word doc is opened with a message: "Enable Javascript to open IPython Notebook". But JavaScript on my browser is already enabled.

This is the prompt of ipython notebook. It seems its open, but isn't start:

[image]

What could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 405 - Method not allowed. Which is odd considering it says it is running

Comment: Have you tried opening it at http://localhost:8888?

Comment: What happens if you do `python -m webbrowser https://google.com`?